# What was the radius of Insight's disruption of Martian regolith?

Tags: mars, landing, insight, regolith, retrorockets

A [NASA animation](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2018/11/15/nasas-cyber-monday-mars-landing-to-deliver-science-firsts/) depicts the Martian regolith being disturbed by the retrorockets of the Insight spacecraft while landing.[image]

Did NASA estimate the radius of the disruption, or was there any indication of what the range of the disruption after it landed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This paper<sup>1</sup> states that there is a

> ...quasi-circular  disturbed  zone  of 15-21  m  radius (~990 
>   m2) around  InSight.

Based on HiRISE imagery and views from InSight cameras.

[image]

<sup>1</sup>[SURFACE  ALTERATION  FROM  LANDING  INSIGHT ON  MARS  AND  ITS  IMPLICATIONS  FOR SHALLOW REGOLITH STRUCTURE](https://elib.dlr.de/132618/1/Williams_et_al.LPSC_2781.pdf).